# How to limit number of checkboxes in a MS Word table column?

Tags: ms-word, checkbox

I have a MS Word document, it will end up as a protected form to be used as a course application.  I have a table with 6 columns, and 15 rows (1 heading and 14 courses):

- In the second last column I have a checkbox in each cell, so the applicant can tick in this column to show which course he would like to come to.
- The applicants can select up to a max of 3 courses from this column.
- In the last column is a text field that allows the applicants to tell us their priority preference, 1, 2 or 3.

I found this link - http://www.wordbanter.com/showthread.php?t=142283 - and subsequently this link - http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/ExclusiveFmFldChbxs.htm - which shows you how to do something similar if the checkboxes were in a row or frame... I tried to tweak the coding but can't seem to get it to work for a column!

And I don't know how to do the priority preference column either!  Can I make it so that the text box is enabled if the corresponding checkbox is selected?  If so, how??

I'm very much a macro virgin so any help you can give on this would be much much appreciated - thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a more simplestic and non too technical answer haha!

I created 3 dropdown menus instead, in order of course preference, and asked the users to select the course of their choice from there... so no need to limit number of checkboxes within a table column :-)

Thanks for reading